# Re-render on state change

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm struggling trying to re-render the component `BookmarkButton` on click on its icon.
Basically, here the scenario. An `Item` could be bookmarked or not.
I use `BookmarkButton` to add/remove item from the bookmarks I want to update the render of `BookmarkButton` to show a star icon (item is bookmarked) or just the outline (item isn't bookmarked). Very common scenario indeed.
The problem is `BookmarkButton` doesn't re-render on state change..

Item component

```
class Item extends Component {
    static navigationOptions = ({ navigation,state }) => ({
        headerTitle: "",
        headerTintColor: 'white',
        headerRight: <RightSide navigation={navigation} /> ,
    })
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
```

RightSide component

```
class RightSide extends Component {

    render(){
        const { navigation } = this.props;
        const { params } = navigation.state;

        return  (
            <View style={{flex:1,flexDirection:"row"}}>
                <BookmarkButton id={params.id} />
            </View>
        )

    }
}
```

BookmarkButton  component

```
 class BookmarkButton extends Component {

        constructor(props)  {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                bookmarked: false
            }
        }
        async componentDidMount(){
        let c = await this.checkBookMark(this.props.id)
        await this.promisedSetState({bookmarked: c})
    }

        async _toggleBookmark(id) {

            let b = await this.checkBookMark(id) //check if the ID is present in bookmarks @returns boolean
                b ? await this.removeBookMark(id) : await this.addBookMark(id)
            this.setState({bookmarked:b})
        }
        promisedSetState = (newState) => {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            this.setState(newState, () => {
                resolve()
            });
        });
    };
        render () {

            let icon = this.state.bookmarked ? "md-star" : "md-star-outline"
            return(
                <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={() => this._toggleBookmark(this.props.id)}
                    <Ionicons name={icon} color="white" size={30} />
                </TouchableOpacity>
            )}
```

Comment: Are you sure the function `_toggleBookmark` is being called? That the state is being updated?

Comment: yes, `_toggleBookmark` is called. I'm not sure the state is updated though.

Comment: There are two possibilities, first the state is not being set. To check that change your setState to `this.setState({bookmarked:b}, () => console.warn(b, this.state.bookmarked))` that will show you what the value of `b` is and what the value of `this.state.bookmarked` is.  The other issue could be that `this.checkBookMark` always returns false.

Comment: ok I noticed the state is updated correctly. The unexpected behaviour is just the first time I press on the button (which makes me thing about the state initialization is wrong). If I repeatedly press on the button multiple times I see the state is correctly updated (the icon changes). I edited the code of `BookmarkButton` adding the constructor and some other methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know what your issue is.

You are checking to see if an item has been bookmarked before. I imagine that if it hasn't been booked marked `this.checkBookMark(id)` will return false. Meaning `b === false`

If it returns false then you will add it to the bookmarked list using `await this.addBookMark(id)`

However, this is the important part. You are then setting the state to the value of `b`, which is `false`. You should be setting the value of the state to `!b`

Your setState should become

`this.setState({bookmarked: !b})`

Comment: yeah I noticed that logic error 1 second before your message :)

Comment: It's the simple things that get us every time. I am glad that it is now sorted for you.